# Setting inbound ip address filter for ssh

Tags: azure, ssh, azure-virtual-machine, inbound-security-rule

I'm trying to set an one IP adresss (dynamic) as the source of inbound ssh rules for azure VM. But when its set to "any" works perfectly but given my local dynamic IP doesn't work(connection timed out).

Also tried giving CIDR block for source, but still confused as to why a single IP doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Most 'Whats my IP' sites will give you your Public IP address that you can use for you NSG.

http://www.hazelnest.com/IPproject/MyIP/ip.php

But i believe the issue you are having is one i have seen in very large company networks,  the IP you get from site is not really the IP for RDP/SSH.

Easiest and guaranteed way is to contact you networking guys to provide you with the information.

Another way is to check the IP you get on the RDP/SSH logs when you connect without restricting NSG. Then use that IP on the NSG, not that depending on the network this might change.

**Linux:**

Check the auth.log under the \var\log

[IMAGE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWp9v.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWp9v.png]

**Windows:**

In the VM's **Event Viewer**, navigate to path below and check the event 22, that should have information.

**Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager**

[IMAGE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdRCQ.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdRCQ.png]

Comment: OOpss... Linux.  Check the `auth.log` under the `\var\log` https://i.imgur.com/yYtfmQR.png